# My elantech fingerprint cannot be detected in lsusb. How can i fix this?

Tags: fingerprint-reader, lsusb

My ELANTECH Fingerprint reader is not detected in lsusb but the touchpad is running. The fingerprint sensor is embedded on the touchpad. My laptop is Asus X509JP.

```
vatsal@vatsal-pc:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:5a11 IMC Networks USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Is it connected via USB? If it is an internal device, it might also be connected via pci. Try with `lspci`.

Comment: Has it been disabled within the BIOS? Some system firmware allows you to disable certain security devices, like a fingerprint reader, from the setup menu.

Comment: Not all fingerprint sensors are supported by Linux.

Comment: my laptop  has ELAN1200 04f3:3087 which is not showing in either lsusb or lspci. I got to know about it in xinput. There are no settings in bios regarding this.